# Adding NSDictionary to an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop

I am not sure what I am missing but i have this for loop below. When I loop through it, the dictionary object gets added to the array like it should each time. But for some reason the next time it loops, it completely replaces all the dictionary object values with the current dictionary value it is looping. So for example I have 5 dictionary objects in my array when it's done looping and all of them have the latest loop values...

```
NSMutableArray *events = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableDictionary *event = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Update"]];

for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i = i + 2){

    [event setValue:[array objectAtIndex:i+1] forKey:@"Event-Type"];
    [event setValue:[array objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"date"];
    [events addObject:event];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to allocate a new `NSMutableDictionary` each iteration of the loop, either at the beginning of each loop (i.e. just move that line into the loop) or when you do addObject you can copy the dictionary using `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: event];`

This is because NSMutableDictionary is an object; It is passed by reference. So you're just putting the same instance of NSMUtableDictionary into your array n times.

You can see this by logging the object at each index of your array at the end, and you can check the memory address to see they're all the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in objective C pass references, not copies. So when you call [events addObject:event] then write to that same event later it gets written over and added newly. Just move the creation of the dictionary inside the for loop and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `alloc init` your dictionary inside the loop and also note addition as per Apple Standard always use `setObject: forKey:` if you are using dictionary. Please refer the below code:-

```
NSMutableArray *events = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Update"]];

for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i = i + 2){
    NSMutableDictionary *event = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [event setObject:[array objectAtIndex:i+1] forKey:@"Event-Type"];
    [event setObject:[array objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"date"];
    [events addObject:event];
}
```